# create json array from multiple mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

for example i have two tables post table and user table, and from these i want to create a json array to pass bootstrap datatable.

My table structure. post table and user table. i want to generate an output table having post details and user details.but user name should be in drop down box.

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
include('config/db_i.php');

$sql_post = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `post_tbl`");
$array = array();
$array['data'] = array();

while($res_post = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_post)){

    $sql_user = mysqli_query($con,"select * from user_tbl where user_id='".$res_post['user_id']."'");
    $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_user);

    //what i'll code here
    $array['data'][] = $res_post; 

}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: I'd have thought you would be able to do a single sql query but join the two tables using the user_id?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the concatenation at query level by joining the two tables together as such :

```
Select ps.post_id, ps.post_title, us.user_id, us.user_name FROM post_tbl AS ps JOIN user_tbl AS us ON ps.user_id = us.user_id
```

That way each row of the fetched array will have the post info and the user info which you can freely pass to bootstrap datatable.

*You can also use NATURAL JOIN